# How do I get ondapyV20 to complete authorization?

Tags: python, algorithm, finance, forex

Here is my code:

```
from oandapyV20 import API
import oandapyV20.endpoints.trades as trades
api = API(access_token="xxx")
accountID = "xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxx"
r = trades.TradesList(accountID)
print("REQUEST:{}".format(r))
rv = api.request(r)
print("RESPONSE:\n{}".format(json.dumps(rv, indent=2)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oanda tester.py", line 10, in <module>
    rv = api.request(r)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\oandapyV20\oandapyV20.py", line 306, in request
    request_args, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\oandapyV20\oandapyV20.py", line 243, in __request
    response.content.decode('utf-8'))
oandapyV20.exceptions.V20Error: {"errorMessage":"Insufficient authorization to perform request."}
```

My token and account info is correct.

This code was copied straight from documentation.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: V20Error: {"errorMessage":"Insufficient authorization to perform request."}  is a token issue. Either the token itself or a correct token used with incorrect environment live/practice mixup

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
from oandapyV20 import  API
import oandapyV20.endpoints.trades as trades
import json

access_token="xxx"
accountID = "xxxx"
client= API(access_token=access_token,environment="live" or "practice")

r = trades.TradesList(accountID)
print("REQUEST:{}".format(r))
rv = client.request(r)
print("RESPONSE:\n{}".format(json.dumps(rv, indent=2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define the client object, you should specify if your account is of type live or practice:

```
client= API(access_token = access_token, environment = "live")
```

Regularly, when you work with practice accounts you define the client object like this:

```
client= API(access_token = access_token)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you have to go into the actual oandapyV20 .py file and look for this:

```
 def __init__(self, access_token, environment="practice",
                 headers=None, request_params=None)...
```

Even though you can pass params when you send to client, for whatever reason it wont take the request because this one part in the oandapyV20 file is set to "practice". Change it here and save the .py file, then the request should work.